# git-log: Split Typechange into Add and Delete

Tags: git

I output a raw diff of a commit using

```
git log -1 --raw <sha1>
```

Now that output can contain `TYPECHANGE` records like this

```
:100644 120000 <old-sha> <new-sha> T My/Changed/File
```

If the raw diff is output in conjuction with a patch like so

```
git log -1 -p --raw <sha1>
```

the file `My/Changed/File` will show up as 2 patches, one for a `DELETION` and another `ADDITION`. I'd like to get the correct filenames from the raw part, and use the diff from the patch output, but since the number of diffs is not equal to the raw diff entries, I cant match them up one-by-one.

Is it possible to tell git to split `TYPECHANGE` entries in the raw diff into a `DELETION/ADDITION` pair, so it looks like this?

```
:100644 000000 <old-sha> 000000000 D My/Changed/File
:000000 120000 000000000 <new-sha> A My/Changed/File
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A type-change entry means that what *was* a *file* is now a *symbolic link*, or vice versa.<sup>1</sup>

There are no *lines* to add or delete.  Git must *completely remove* the old file-or-symlink—whichever it was—and completely install the new symlink-or-file.  The reason `git log -p` or `git show` shows this as "delete one name, add new entity with same name" is that it really, actually requires two steps ... but those two steps represent a single *change* when comparing old (`a/`) commit vs new (`b/`) commit.

If you are just trying to match the fields up, just remember that all `T`-status changes are achieved by two separate operations: delete the old, add the new.

---

<sup>1</sup>It could also represent a change from file to gitlink, or vice versa, or from symlink to gitlink, or vice versa.  I think this covers all the possibilities, as a non-tree becoming a tree, or vice versa, is always represented by add/delete of the files that cause the tree to exist.  If Git could store empty tree objects, Git might want a `T` mode for empty-directory-to-file or vice versa, though.

Comment: Yes, I know what a typechange does, but how does that answer my question? I know it requires 2 steps, but i want this also reflected in the raw diff (by 2 lines).

Comment: You can't get that. (But why do you care? The single `T` line has all the same information, just encoded differently.)

Comment: Yes, thanks. Thats what I did now anyways, I just "synthesized" an add and delete entry from the `T` line. The reason I wanted it from git is that I can be sure the order of the pair is always DEL/ADD, since otherwise my raw lines wont match up with the generated patch order.